# How do I transfer a folder from my Windows to Xubuntu 22.04?

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, windows, directory, transfer

I'm using Xubuntu 22.04 on VirtualBox, all that is installed on my Windows laptop. Now the thing is,  I want to transfer a folder from my Windows desktop onto my Xubuntu desktop. How can I achieve this? Thank you! :)

Comment: This is a windows/virtualbox problem not one you fix in Ubuntu.

Comment: ok so how would I be able to fix that in VirtualBox and windows?

Comment: @Rinzwind - Actually, this is an Ubuntu question, since ***VB Guest Additions*** should be installed on the guest (Xubuntu).

Comment: No you install them in windows in vbox.

Comment: Yeah. You are right. But, most of the times, GA will come together on the host, but you have to install it manually on the guest.

Answer (score 0):

Install [VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) on your Xubuntu *guest VM* and use ***Shared Folders***.

Shared folders physically reside on the *host* (Windows in your case) and are then shared with the *guest* (Xubuntu in your case).

Please, read the VirtualBox documentation for more detailed information: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

You can also use the [***Drag and Drop***](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-dnd) functionality, if it is available.